# Firebase Nested Index Query Rules

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Last night I was trying to index a nested object in firebase's database. Below is my object data and rules. Currently on orderedBy locID it is returning index not defined. Would appreciate any help thanks!

My Data:

[image: My Data:]

My Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "locations": {
      "$uid": {
        ".indexOn": ["locID"]
      }
    },
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The code that triggers the error:

```
locData = db.child("Locations").order_by_child("locID").equal_to(someID).get()
```

The above is returning index not defined, using the pyrebase wrapper.

Comment: Can you show the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're skipping a level in your query.

Firebase will query the immediate children of the location on which you execute the query. So in your case, it will query items `10S` and `12S` and try to order/filter on `locID`. Neither of these nodes has a child `locID`, since that property is one level deeper in the tree.

Pyrebase likely talks against the Firebase REST API, which will fail when there is no index for the field you're trying to order/filter on.

It's a bit hard to be certain for your use-case, but in general the solution to this problem is to keep a *reverse index*. In this case that could be a list that keeps track of the `10S`/`12S` thing for each `locID`.

```
locByLocID: {
  5689: "10S",
  8223: "12S"
}
```